# XPath para obter todos os nós filhos img

Tags: php, xpath, php-domxpath

Tenho um arquivo HTML e estou tentando usar o DOM para encontrar o valor de cada `span` e recuperar o valor do atributo da imagem `data-src`

abaixo o codido html

```html
<div class="content">
   <a class="item" href="#" title="">
      <figure>
        <img src="#" data-src="#" class="">
    </figure>
      <p class="info">
         <span class="name">loren</span>
         <span class="author">loren</span>
         <span class="description">loren<span>
      </p>
   </a>
   <a class="item" href="#" title="">
      <figure>
        <img src="#" data-src="#" class="">
    </figure>
      <p class="info">
         <span class="name">loren</span>
         <span class="author">loren</span>
         <span class="description">loren<span>
      </p>
   </a>
</div>
```

precorro a `DOMDocument` usando o `$xpath->query` o resultado é que consigo recuperar todos os valores de todas as `spans`.

Agora minha dúvida é como a agora obter o valor do atributo `data-src` da img tentei alguns códigos mais sem sucesso.

```
$body = "URL SITE";
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($body);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath = $xpath->query('//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]');


if (!is_null($xpath)) {

    foreach ($xpath as $element) {

        $nodes = $element->childNodes;

        foreach ($nodes as $node) {

            echo $node->nodeValue. "<br/>";
        }
    } 
}
```